# Winform Set readonly for tablelayoutpanel C#

Tags: c#, winforms, readonly, tablelayoutpanel

I have a tablelayoutpanel which contains many controls. I wanna lock this tablelayoutpanel but I can copy data in fields. Tablelayoutpanel has only ENABLED property --> I cannot copy data in them. Please help me to lock tablelayoutpanel and can copy in these fields.

Comment: LOCK means user cannot edit but they can copy data

Comment: Almost. Because I have many controls in tablelayoutpanel, so I cannot set ReadOnly one by one.

Comment: copy data into a field is editing the field. so as grant already suggested.. you need some way of at least explaining what you mean exactly, and maybe even better try to explain why you want this (as maybe there is a better solution for your problem on a higher level). for example, adding a second panel which is editable, and copy over from that panel to the locked one on the press of a button.

Comment: I have a tablelayoutpanel which contains many controls (textbox, combobox,....). When I submit form, I need lock all controls in tablelayoutpanel (like disable property) but end user want to copy data in all textbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing in the `TableLayoutPanel` that allows for that functionality.

Instead, loop through all the controls, look at the type, and set the property you need:

```
foreach (var control in tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Cast<Control>())
{
    var tb = control as TextBoxBase;

    if (tb != null)
        tb.ReadOnly = true;       // controls like TextBox and RichTextBox
    else
        control.Enabled = false;  // all other controls
}
```